# can't see latest GIT commits after checking out an older version in SourceTree, no remote

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have used GIT quit a bit (basic use), just came across this one. I have local repository and checkout an older version to see if a particular featured worked or not. After checking that, I wanted to get back to the latest commit and I dont see those commits.

I search various other answers and tried a number of commands, but nothing worked. I am using SourceTree

**As you can see latest commit that can be seen is of 28Nov but today is 5th Dec and I did commit changes in the past few days, but I can't see them.** I only have master branch, local repository only

### Edit

Note when I click the "search tab" and enter relevent keywords, it does pull the newer commits but I can't seem to check it out, at least easily

[image]

Comment: Are there other branches in the remote repository? Seems like there is only a master branch in your local repository, that is set to the 'sms works' commit. Did you commit your changes in the same local repository? How exactly did you check out this "old version", what commands did you use?

Comment: you can still get stuff back through rev IDs by using `git reflog` just in case, so it's not like you actually _lost_ something. You can always move the branch pointer to where it was before.

Comment: @kowsky by double clicking on the older version in sourcetree. I have no remote, just local repository. Thanks

I look at reflog and that might help I think but shouldn't this be a straightforward thing to go back to the latest. I have done that before but this is the first time I can't go back to the most recent.

Comment: @HammadKhan As a sidenote, if you don't currently use any remote repo, it can't hurt to set one just in case (even on the same machine, it doesn't need to be distant)

Comment: Nice but this is just less important work sort off and I just want myself to be able to revert back to 'good' version, just in case. So do not feel the  need to setup remote :) + my project is heavy also